# Multilanguage site from plain HTML/JS

Tags: asp.net, resx

I got plain .html and .js files (lots of code) and web site needs to support multiple languages. I know how to use ASP.NET local and global resource files, so...

...is there any less painful way to achieve this, than rewriting all the .html to .aspx and write httpHandler for .js files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a really cool service from Google which translate your pages on the fly..
https://translate.google.com/translate_tools

It can even save your preferred translation so that you can personalize translations for your website

even Microsoft also provide similar service 
http://www.microsoft.com/web/solutions/mstranslator.aspx